# determine newest svn tag from hudson for deploy

Tags: svn, maven, hudson, maven-release-plugin

We use Subversion for source control along with Maven for dependency management/ release preparation and Hudson as the CI server. The maven release prepare does the release tagging and creates a new tag in SVN. I would like to run the deploy job in Hudson off the latest tag (by default) and off other tags on demand.

Is there a way to get the latest SVN tag information in Hudson and pass it to a parameterized job.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible, provided you add a build action which list the tags of your svn repo, using [`svn switch`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html), and [`svn ls`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.list.html):

```
svn switch http://your/svn/repo/tags/'svn ls http://your/svn/repo/tags | tail -n 1' repo
```

You will find other options in the SO question "[Automating builds from subversion tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521905/automating-builds-from-subversion-tags)"